# Select greatest/max value using custom order in pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have some sample data which looks like this, `df1`:

```
| id1 | id2  | yyyy_mm_dd |
|-----|------|------------|
| 1   | 3245 | 2021-01-01 |
| 1   | 4564 | 2021-01-01 |
| 1   | 3546 | 2021-01-01 |
| 1   | 632  | 2021-01-01 |
| 1   | 521  | 2021-01-01 |
| 2   | 7413 | 2021-01-01 |
| ... | ...  | ...        |
```

I then have a second `df` which tracks a `status` per day for each `id2`, named `df2`:

```
| yyyy_mm_dd | id2  | product | status |
|------------|------|---------|--------|
| 2021-01-01 | 3245 | p1      | i      |
| 2021-01-01 | 3245 | p2      | f_c    |
| 2021-01-01 | 3245 | p3      | n_c    |
| 2021-01-01 | 4564 | p1      | n_c    |
| 2021-01-01 | 4564 | p2      | n_c    |
| 2021-01-01 | 4564 | p3      | n_c    |
| 2021-01-01 | 3546 | p1      | f_c    |
| 2021-01-01 | 3546 | p2      | n_c    |
| 2021-01-01 | 3546 | p3      | n_c    |
| 2021-01-01 | 7413 | p1      | f_c    |
| ...        | ...  | ...     | ..     |
```

I would like to create an output dataframe, whereby `id1` inherits the `status` from `id2`. The problem I'm facing is that there is a one-to-many relationship between `id1` and `id2` so it's hard to take a status to inherit.

With that in mind, I would like to take the `greatest` / `max` value from status but this is also difficult since they are strings. Though, there is a hierarchy such that  `i > f_c > n_c`.

Based on the above, I would like my output to look like this:

```
| yyyy_mm_dd | id1 | product | status |
|------------|-----|---------|--------|
| 2020-01-01 | 1   | p1      | i      |
| 2020-01-01 | 1   | p2      | f_c    |
| 2020-01-01 | 1   | p3      | n_c    |
| 2020-01-01 | 2   | p1      | f_c    |
```

With the output, `id1` = 1 inherits the `i` `status` for `p1` because `i` is the greatest status among `id2` = `(3245, 4564, 3546)`. The same can be seen for `id1` = 1 and `p2`, as `f_c` ends up as the `status` due to it being the max among `id2` = `(3245, 4564, 3546)`.

---

I know I can join the data like so:

```
df3 = (
    df1
    .join(df2, on = ['yyyy_mm_dd', 'id2']
)
```

But I am unsure how to take the greatest `status` among the `id2`s since it's non-numeric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join `df` with `df2` on `id2` and `yyyy_mm_dd` columns, then calculate a row number and orderby a when expression for custom ordering of `status`

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

result = df1.join(df2, ["yyyy_mm_dd", "id2"]).withColumn(
    "rn",
    F.row_number().over(
        Window.partitionBy("yyyy_mm_dd", "id1", "product").orderBy(
            F.when(F.col("status") == "i", 1).when(F.col("status") == "f_c", 2).when(F.col("status") == "n_c", 3)
        )
    )
).filter("rn = 1").drop("id2", "rn")

result.show()
#+----------+---+-------+------+
#|yyyy_mm_dd|id1|product|status|
#+----------+---+-------+------+
#|2021-01-01|  1|     p2|   f_c|
#|2021-01-01|  2|     p1|   f_c|
#|2021-01-01|  1|     p1|    i |
#|2021-01-01|  1|     p3|   n_c|
#+----------+---+-------+------+
```

Or if you prefer using `groupBy` with `max`:

```
result = df1.join(df2, ["yyyy_mm_dd", "id2"]).groupBy("yyyy_mm_dd", "id1", "product").agg(
    F.max(
        F.when(F.col("status") == "i", 3).when(F.col("status") == "f_c", 2).when(F.col("status") == "n_c", 1)
    ).alias("max_status")
).select(
    "yyyy_mm_dd", "id1", "product",
    F.when(F.col("max_status") == 3, "i")
     .when(F.col("max_status") == 2, "f_c")
     .when(F.col("max_status") == 1, "n_c").alias("status")
)
```